# Dependency Issues Running a JRuby Thread

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, jruby, jruby-rack

I'm running on JRuby 1.6.7 with Rails 3.0.2. I have a few methods that call REST services.

It would be nice to execute them concurrently, so instead of each one taking 2 seconds to return totaling 6 seconds. I'll get the data back in about 2 seconds.

I can't use Fibers because the following calls use blocking io and cannot be modified so I cannot code them to work 'cooperatively'. I'm trying to use preemptive threads.

I have a simple call inside a thread as follows.

```
Thread.new do
  callrest1() 
end
```

Though I get the following error when this code executes inside the thread. I'm guessing it cannot find the correct files/classes because its in a new thread? Any ideas?

Expected /home/joe/ruby/analysis/app/models/dashboard/reports.rb to define Dashboard::Reports
Rails.root: /home/joe/ruby/analysis

```
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
activesupport (3.0.5) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:492:in `load_missing_constant'
activesupport (3.0.5) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:183:in `const_missing'
                      org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1615:in `each'
activesupport (3.0.5) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `const_missing'
activesupport (3.0.5) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:503:in `load_missing_constant'
activesupport (3.0.5) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:183:in `const_missing'
                      org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1615:in `each'
activesupport (3.0.5) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `const_missing'
                      app/controllers/dashboard/index_controller.rb:297:in `generateReport'
                      app/controllers/dashboard/index_controller.rb:223:in `index'
```

Comment: Strange, maybe it does nothing but, have you anebled "threadsafe!" in environment config?

Comment: this might be a kind of a race condition while loading classes. as Luke already stated above make sure you're threadsafe! (it will eager load all classes up front in production). also you might try to `require 'dashboard/reports'` to load `Dashboard::Reports` before spinning the thread and see where it goes ...